# Update table when dropdownoption changes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, onchange

I have a portion of a table whose values depend on the value in my dropdownlist. How can I update the the table when the selected option of the dropdownlist changes.

grid

```
@foreach (var choice in ViewData.Model.Options where choiceId == ViewData.Model.choiceLevelId)
                    {
                        <tr class='gridrow'>
                            <td>.....
```

dropdown

```
 <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.choiceLevelId,
                            (
                             ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What table are you talking about? ASP.NET MVC has no knowledge of tables or chairs. It works with Models, Controllers and Views.

So you have a View in which you have rendered a `<select>` box and you want upon changing the value of this select box by the user to invoke a Controller Action passing the newly selected value to the server so that it can perform some processing. Am I right?

You will have to use javascript in your View in order to subscribe to the change event of this dropdown. Then you have a couple of possibilities:

- Use an AJAX request to send the selected value to the server.
- Redirect the current browser (using `window.location.href`) to the controller action passing it the selected value as action argument.

Depending on your requirements you could pick the technique that suites best for you.

Let me illustrate the first approach with an example using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // subscribe to the .change event of the dropdowns
        $('select').change(function() {
            // fetch the newly selected value
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            // send it as an AJAX request to some controller action
            $.post('@Url.Action("Foo")', { value: selectedValue }, function(result) {
                // this will be invoked in the case of success of the AJAX call
                // TODO: do something with the results returned by the controller action
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and your controller action that will handle the AJAX request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string value)
{
    // this action will be invoked when the user changes the selection
    // in one of the dropdown lists and passed the newly selected value.
    // So using this new value you could perform the desired processing
    // on your model here and return a view. Since this action was invoked
    // with an AJAX call you could return a JSON string to the client indicating
    // the success or failure of whatever processing you were intending to perform 
    // here

    ...

}
```

---

UPDATE:

If you wanted to submit the form containing the dropdowns when the selection changes you could use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // subscribe to the .change event of the dropdowns
        $('select').change(function() {
            // trigger the submission of the containing form:
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The table i was referring to is pretty much the entire form. All opf my data is present in a table including the dropdown. I want to update a which members of my model show based on the select. for instance if my model was cars and on the list i chose red only red cars info should render. I don't think i should have to go to the controller because all of the data is already accessible to the view ist just a matter of filtering.

Comment: @atbyrd, so you want to submit the form, right? In this case you could subscribe to the change event of the dropdowns as I showed in my answer and manually trigger the submission of the containing form, just like that: `$(this).closest('form').submit();`. I will update my answer to include that.

Comment: i tried using this $("select").change(function(){
    alert("hello");
});  To subscribe to the change event but nothing happens.

Comment: don't want to submit anything just present data

Comment: @atbyrd, did you wrap your subscription into a `$(document).ready` as shown in my answer? Also if you don't want to submit the form but just the present selection then you are back to my 2 suggestions: AJAX or window.location.href to perform a full redirect. Up to you to decide which suits better to your specific scenario and requirements.

Comment: @atbyrd, if it's inside document ready it should work. If it doesn't it's probably because you have some other error in a portion of your code that you haven't shown and unfortunately I have no way of knowing. That's why I suggested you using a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug. It will help you understand your errors.