# How to stick together MVC4, DropDownList and C# Class?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` that contains "Station" codes.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Station", null, new { id = "dd_custom"});
```

The `DropDownList` is filled by `ViewData["Station"]` (list of SelectListItem).

My goal is simple: when the `DropDownList` **CHANGES** (In bold, because I know onchange exists, but cannot make it work.), I want the `@ViewBag.CurrentStation` to be equal to the station chosen.

What I've tried:

1. Javascript via [this website](http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2009/11/29/ASPNET-MVC-DropdownList-PostBack.aspx), [this website](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cascading-DropDownList-in-833683f9), and *many* other websites.
2. Ajax

Still, I can't figure out how to make this dropdownlist to interact with my Controller (base Controller from the MVC4 template (Internet Application)).

The easiest way would be to interact from my index.cshtml to HomeController.cs, but I can't figure out how.

Can someone help ?

Thanks

---

Edit: I need the Station Code for all my pages. The User can only modify the Station on the Home page, but I need the Station on the other page to produce reports. Global Variable would be the answer maybe, like using Application["VarName"], but still, don't know how to interact with my DropDownList => C# Class.

Comment: What is your end goal of what you're trying to achieve here? Do you want to submit the selection and then use it somewhere else? Or as indicated by your links, are you trying to change what's displayed on the same screen when the selection changes?

If you wrap the whole thing in an `@Html.BeginForm`, and place an `<input type=submit />` in there as well, you'll get a form which posts back to your controller - you just need an action `public void SomeAction(string Station)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you store in the `ViewData`, `ViewBag` will exists for only one request. Say for ex. when the dropdown changes if you are making a request to server and set the new value to `@ViewBag.CurrentStation` but that won't be available for the next request because it's gone.

If you want to call some controller action when the dropdown changes you could do that through ajax using jquery.

To submit the selected value of dropdown to server you can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902320/update-table-when-dropdownoption-changes).

If you want the current station to be persisted for more than one request for an user then you can use session.

**Server-Side**

```
public class StationController: Controller
{
   public ActionResult SaveCurrentStation(int stationId)
   {
       Session["CurrentStation"] = stationId;

       return new EmptyResult();
   }
}
```

**Client-Side**

```
$("#dropdownId").change(function(){
   var selStationId = $(this).val();
   $.post("/Station/SaveCurrentStation", {stationId: selStationId });
});
```

Comment: Yes, (check the Edit), I would like the Station to be a public variable through my program to use it to produce reports. Thanks.

Comment: Store the current station in session so you can access from anywhere. I would better suggest to create a wrapper class around http session so you can better unit test the classes that reference session.

Comment: But can you tell me how to: DropDownList => onchange => C# Function ? Thanks

Comment: I tried the Controller + 
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $("#dd_custom").change(function () {
                        var selStationId = $(this).val();
                        $.post("/StationController/SaveCurrentStation", { stationId: selStationId });
                        alert(selStationID);
                    });  
                                                       
               </script>

Without any luck, thanks for the answer

Comment: There is a small mistake in the script. It will be "/Station/SaveCurrentStation" not "/StationController/SaveCurrentStation" and you have to return a empty result from action.

Comment: Where to put the script? (I put the script <script> $("#dropdownId").change(function(){
   var selStationId = $(this).val();
   $.post("/Station/SaveCurrentStation", {stationId: selStationId });
}); </script>

Under the @Html.DropDownList("Station",
                                      null,
                               new { @id = "dd_custom" });

Comment: You have to put the script at the end of the view and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: It just does nothing (Like if the onchange doesn't get fired, I put alert at the end of the javascript to see if it works, but it apparently doesn't :/)